# Photoshop drawing effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, photoshop-effects

I'm trying to create an image similar to the one below. Outside lines look like they are drawn with a pencil and the colored fill doesn't touch the outside line everywhere. Is there a simple way to recreate that? Is there some kind of an effect or do I have to draw it manually?

[image: drawing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Lucian says](/a/101620/52050), doing this in Illustrator would be easier and may be more appropriate. If you can find (or make) a brush that fits what you need in Photoshop though, you can use that brush to stroke a path drawn with the Pen Tool...

- First set your brush with the Brush Tool active.
- Then draw your path with the Pen Tool.
  Make sure the Pen Tool mode is set to "Path" (not "Shape" or "Pixel")–This will create a work path (visible in the Paths panel).
- With the Pen Tool still active and the work path selected, right click your path and choose "Stroke Path..."
- Set "Tool" to "Brush" in the Stroke Path dialog and hit OK.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drawing is actually an illustration and Adobe Illustrator is better at working with this type of shapes. You can apply brush strokes to any (yes) manually drawn lines, so the resulting lines can look like painted, or brushed, or drawn in pencil. See [this post](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-illustrators-paintbrush-tool-and-brush-panel--vector-301) for example.

The resulting vector file format is another reason to do this in Illustrator. When finished, you can import or simply paste from AI back to PS if needed.